# jQuery - Ajax async not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Ajax call in jQuery like this...

```
    function my_call(identifier) {

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://www.example.com/?" + identifier,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },

    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "dataType"   : "json",
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {         
        console.log(response);
    });

}
```

And I am calling it 10 times for different identifiers like this...

```
my_call(1);
my_call(2);
my_call(3);
my_call(4);
my_call(5);
```

I have set async to true so had assumed these calls would all happening at the same time, but instead I seem to get the results print to the console one after the other with a bit of a delay in between.

Am I doing it correctly, or is there a different way to call the function? I am trying  to reduce the time it takes to return the results.

Comment: _"I have set async to true so had assumed these calls would all happening at the same time"_ You do understand what asynchronous means don't you?

Comment: Don't have to set `async:true`. That is default. If there is much of a delay it is likely server side related. Inspect the actual requests in browser dev tools network

Comment: JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded so they're not happening at the same time.

Comment: Async isn't exactly parallel, it's just non-blocking.

Comment: Also some of those options are useless on a GET request

Comment: @charliefl : which ones in particular are redundant options?

Comment: Look at the network tab to get a better idea of the order and timing of the calls.

Comment: You aren't sending any data so processing is pointless as is mimeType and contentType on a GET there is no content sent and crossDomain is really only for testing jsonp

Comment: @charlietfl : Thanks for that, obvious now you spelled it out!

Comment: For what you are doing `$.getJSON( "http://www.example.com/?" + identifier).done(function (response) {...` will do what you need. Is a shorthand wrapper for `$.ajax`

Comment: Chnage your server script so that it sleeps for a random number of seconds. Then you'll see that the log messages happen out of order.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX function calls are occcurring one after another. They are still [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean) as they are not waiting for the previous AJAX calls to finish before executing (which would be the behavior had you set `async` to `false`). AJAX calls are supposed to work that way; you send a request over to the server and **wait** for the response to execute a function. To make the AJAX calls finish faster, you will have to optimize your server-side code (if possible). Also, it is unnecessary to set the `async` property to `true` as that is the default. Javascript is single-threaded, so you cannot execute many functions at the **exact same time**.